# laravel - how get limit one record

Tags: php, laravel

can't get last record from table,
my table has many records me need get only one last..

i have this query:

me need get last join query records

```
->leftJoin('vtask as avt', function($q) {
                    $q->on('avt.vehicle_id', '=', 't.vehicle_id')
                        ->on('avt.shift_start', '<=', 'dqe.time')->orderBy('avt.shift_start', 'desc');
                })
                ->leftJoin('vreplace as avr', function($q) {
                    $q->on('avr.vehicle_id', '=', 't.vehicle_id')
                        ->on(DB::raw("avr.time"), '>=', 'dqe.time')->orderBy('avr.time', 'desc');
                })
```

```
DB::table('dqevent','dqe')
                ->join('transport as t','t.id', '=', 'dqe.transport')
                ->join('vehicle as v','v.id', '=', 't.vehicle_id')
                ->leftJoin('vtask as avt', function($q) {
                    $q->on('avt.vehicle_id', '=', 't.vehicle_id')
                        ->on('avt.shift_start', '<=', 'dqe.time')->orderBy('avt.shift_start', 'desc');
                })
                ->leftJoin('vreplace as avr', function($q) {
                    $q->on('avr.vehicle_id', '=', 't.vehicle_id')
                        ->on(DB::raw("avr.time"), '>=', 'dqe.time')->orderBy('avr.time', 'desc');
                })
                ->leftJoin('ar as r','r.id', '=', DB::raw('COALESCE(avt.route_id, avr.route_id)'))
                ->leftJoin('driver as ad', 'ad.id', '=', DB::raw('COALESCE(avt.driver_id, avr.driver_id)'))
                ->selectRaw(
                    "dqe.id,
                    r.short_name,
                    dqe.lat,
                    dqe.lon
                ")
                ->orderBy('dqe.id','desc')->paginate(15);
```

get last record from my table :)

Comment: Well surely the "last" is just the first with a reversed sort order? `->first()`

Comment: no :( in left join dont have first()  function

Comment: i try this  
`
$avt = DB::raw("(select max(avt.id) from asdu_vehicle_task avt where avt.vehicle_id = t.vehicle_id and avt.shift_start <= dqe.time)");
->on('avt.id', '=', $avt);
`
but i get slow query

@Scuzzy

Comment: Perhapps you need to review your table indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i change my code and insert new index in my table

Migrate file

```
$table->index(['driver_id', 'vehicle_id', 'shift_start', 'shift_end', 'route_id']);
```

Controller

```
$avt = DB::raw("(select max(avt.id) from vtask  avt where avt.vehicle_id = t.vehicle_id and avt.shift_start <= dqe.time)");

->leftJoin('vreplace as avr', function($q) {
                        $q->on('avr.vehicle_id', '=', 't.vehicle_id')
                            ->on(DB::raw("avr.time"), '>=', 'dqe.time')->orderBy('avr.time', 'desc');
     ->on('avt.id', '=', $avt)
                    })
```

Answer (score 1):

To return one last record from your "dqevent" table, you can modify the query with `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT` and `first`:

```
DB::table('dqevent','dqe')
    ->join('transport as t','t.id', '=', 'dqe.transport')
    ->join('vehicle as v','v.id', '=', 't.vehicle_id')
    ->leftJoin('vtask as avt', function($q) {
        $q->on('avt.vehicle_id', '=', 't.vehicle_id')
            ->on('avt.shift_start', '<=', 'dqe.time')->orderBy('avt.shift_start', 'desc');
    })
    ->leftJoin('vreplace as avr', function($q) {
        $q->on('avr.vehicle_id', '=', 't.vehicle_id')
            ->on(DB::raw("avr.time"), '>=', 'dqe.time')->orderBy('avr.time', 'desc');
    })
    ->leftJoin('ar as r','r.id', '=', DB::raw('COALESCE(avt.route_id, avr.route_id)'))
    ->leftJoin('driver as ad', 'ad.id', '=', DB::raw('COALESCE(avt.driver_id, avr.driver_id)'))
    ->selectRaw(
        "dqe.id,
        r.short_name,
        dqe.lat,
        dqe.lon
    ")
    ->orderBy('dqe.id','desc')
    ->limit(1)
    ->first();
```

**You can read about SQL syntax rules on example of PostgreSQL** (almost identical to MySQL, Oracle and MS SQL from point of view [SQL99 STD](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/%7Elen/sql1999.pdf)).

[SELECT with WHERE filtration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html)

[LIMIT and OFFSET pagination](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-limit.html)

[ORDER BY ASC/DESC sorting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-order.html)

[GROUP BY and HAVING aggregation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-agg.html)

[UNION / INTERSECT / EXCEPT combination](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-union.html)

[JOIN joining](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-join.html) and [more joining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))

I know you may use mybatis, doctrine orm, linq, yalinqo, timetoogo pinq, hibernate + spring data jpa, jooq or laravel query builder frameworks, but they are just syntax sugar for SQL99 subdialect.